# Programming Logic - What is a good, universal shorthand term for a second part to a hypothesis?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I was wondering if there was a technical term to a second part to a hypothesis? Like:

```
(X & Y) → Z
```

What would `Y` be known as? Or what would `X` be known as for that matter? Some of the options I have considered using is "bit" and "quadrant" but I don't believe these to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X and Y are called parameter values in discrete maths. The statement "if X and Y then Z" is called a proposition. Note that if X is not true, this does not imply Z is not true.

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Discrete_Mathematics/Logic

But sometimes you combine propositions with AND etc. For example from the link above:
    p represents the proposition "Henry VIII had six wives".
    q represents the proposition "The English Civil War took place in the nineteenth century".

is p AND q, true or false.

also its valid to say if p AND q then r

(we can question whether this is a true proposition overall, depending on what the propositions p,q,r are)

Comment: I've edited my answer a bit when I realised the proposition is the overall (X&Y) -> Z and the X,Y are parameters.

Comment: I think I've answered your question anyway. If you look in my link you will find more information.